# AWS Update Service and Enable Execute Command without losing container data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Without going into the detail, there were changes to the data within the container that I would like to keep in the container.

However, the ECS services have disabled command line that disallowed by to perform some export action. How can I retrieve them or possibly enable execute command without losing the data?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. ECS tasks are ephemeral and you should never store important data inside the task itself. Any data you want to persist in your ECS task should be written to a mounted EFS volume or an external database or something.